# React Global Memoization

Tags: reactjs, memoization

I have the following React test app:

```js
class MemoTestApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     showOverlay: false,
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <MemoComponent str="Hello World" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({showOverlay: true})} value="Show Overlay"/>
        </div>
        {this.state.showOverlay && (
          <div className="overlay">
            <h2>Overlay</h2>
            <MemoComponent str="Hello World" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Component = (props) => {
  console.info('render ' + props.str);
  return <div>{props.str}</div>;
}

const MemoComponent = React.memo(Component);

ReactDOM.render(<MemoTestApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

As you can see, there is a memoized functional component which is rendered twice with the same props. The first rendering takes place immediately, the second one after the user presses the button.

However, the component really is rendered twice, as you can see in the console. `React.memo` prevents the second rendering of the first instance of the component, but the second instance seems to "now know" that this component has already been rendered with the given props.

Is there a way to make Memoization "global", i.e. so that rendered outputs are shared between different instances of the component?

What is the reason that `React.memo` is not global by default?

Comment: Is your actual goal to have only one `MemoComponent` instance and move it around in the React tree, when overlay is toggled?

Comment: @ford04 No that's not my goal (but could be a scenario where my "global memoization" makes sense too). I'm asking generally, if the same component appears at different places in the UI, maybe with the same props, then why does it need to be rendered twice? I.e., why is memoization local and not global?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Components are reusable, this is by design.

They may have their own state, for example a counter. Or they have side effects, e.g. own intervals, custom logic depending on the DOM nodes.

For that reason, they have to be separate "instances" depending where they live on the DOM (parent node, index or `key`), and are separately rendered. The result is then memoized per component "instance".

Comment: Thanks, but this is a functional component. The whole point of a functional component is that it is stateless (not talking about hooks) and without side effects. So I don't see a reason why memoization should not work globally.

Comment: I think the benefits wouldn't outweight the optimization cost. How should that type of optimization work? React would need to check whether the component uses hooks, and that any component composed inside follows the same rules. As "global components" can still be different because of different props, such a global cache would need to keep track of props, and manage cache size. On the other hand, the percentage of simple components that would apply to global cache (by given rules) is IMHO very small, and the probability that there are many instance with same props is also small.

Comment: I see your second point. The use cases are mostly edge cases. However, as I understand it, all the necessary ingredients are already there. For memoization to work, React already needs to keep track of the props, and manage cache size. The cache is already there. I'm just asking, why isn't the memoization cache global? I don't see a point why it should be more efficient or easier to implement locally.